# Joining two lists in Python:

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays (A & B).
I would like to calculate the % of users of array A , who are included in array B.
I have tried but I can´t find the solution.

Comment: `1.0 * len(set(A) & set(B)) / len(set(B))`

Comment: Are these numpy arrays?

Comment: Your title says "lists" but your question says "arrays". Are they Python lists, [array.array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html)s, Numpy arrays, or something else? Also, do either of these "arrays" contain duplicate items?

Comment: Can you have duplicate users in either array? And if so do they weigh in?

Answer (score 10):

```
100.0 * sum((x in B) for x in A) / len(A)
```

If `B` is large, use a set for efficiency:

```
100.0 * len(set(B).intersection(A)) / len(A)
```

Answer (score 5):

The most pyhtonic way is like Rogalski above commented.

Python in my opinion is very strong at sets:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

you can make an intersection in two ways

set(A) & set(B) or set(A).intersection(set(B))

And the formula is like mentioned above (just corrected)

```
100 * len(set(A) & set(B)) / len(set(A))
```

Comment: The question says "% of users of array A" so I guess the denominator should be `len(A)`.

Comment: .intersection can take an iterable that is not a set so the second call is unnecessary and may as well just be `set(A) & set(B)`

Answer (score 0):

You only need to create one set and sum the times an element in a is in the set of the members in b:

```
st  = set(b)

perc = sum((ele in st for ele in a),0.0) / len(a) * 100
```

If you actually have numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

a, b = [1, 3], [1, 4,3]
perc = np.in1d(a, b).sum() / 100.0 / len(a)
```